# Android SDK and AVD manager not opening. "Exception in thread 'main' org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Cannot set text"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, environment-variables

Using Android Studio, I notice that my AVDs don't open anymore, and my SDK manager won't open at all. To my best knowledge, I have the PATH variables correctly set up. I know other people have this problem, but their solutions didn't work for me, as I'm getting a different error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/StWyH.png

I guess I should also note that eclipse isn't working either. No error messages, it just gets stuck at the loading screen and never opens. However, Android Studio works flawlessly (other than not being able to launch AVDs or SDK manager)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are couple of things that aren't clear but it seems to me that you haven't downloaded the Android SDK (I assume) but simply copied it from somewhere to C:/>Program files. If you have downloaded the SDK it would have been in the C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
I reckoned that some times copying works and sometimes it doesn't.
Here is my advice move this SDK out of C:> into any other drive (You'll need it later) and download and install Android SDK manually but as I know SDK is very large file . Once you have installed the downloaded SDK , copy all the contents of the previous SDK and replace it with the just installed SDK . Hope that works

Comment: Is everything OK with java SE

Comment: Open CMD and java enter

Comment: I don't understand. My java -version returns 1.8.0_31